# Finding a suitable solver

Tags: linear-programming, quadratic-programming

I have a problem finding a solver that can solve a mathematical programming model with a quasi quadratic object function. I have tried some commercially available quadratic and non-linear solvers, but they have all turned out unfeasible solutions. The model has the following object function with:

$$\mbox{Min} [Z] = \sum_i (x(i)^2  + a( e^{d\,x(i)} – x(i) – 1)) ;   $$

$i = 0.....n$;   and with linear constraints.

The function is continuous and has a single minimum at $x = 0$ with $dZ/dx=0$.  At $a = 0$ this is a true quadratic function. I assumed that a quadratic solver could solve this but those I tried failed.

I want to know if someone could recommend a suitable solver to this problem?

Comment: Funny, I've read the title as "Finding a suitable lover"...

Comment: @AlexM. Also difficult to do given commercially available software.

Comment: Try MOSEK: it can solve separable convex problems http://docs.mosek.com/7.1/pythonapi/index.html